# how to add a points system to an app preferences DataStore Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, datastore

I'm working on a **Quiz app** and I'm trying to **add a points system** to the app so that **everytime the user gets a question right he gets a +1pts**.
and for storing the points I use **jetpack compose preferences Datastore**.
the problem is whenever I want to add a point to the already saved points it doesn't work.

> this is my PointsData

```
class PointsData(private val context: Context) {
    //create the preference datastore
    companion object{
      private val Context.datastore : DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("points")
        val CURRENT_POINTS_KEY = intPreferencesKey("points")
    }
    //get the current points
    val getpoints: Flow<Int> =context.datastore.data.map { preferences->
        preferences[CURRENT_POINTS_KEY] ?: 0
    }
    // to save current points
    suspend fun SaveCurrentPoints(numPoints : Int){
        context.datastore.edit {preferences ->
            preferences[PointsData.CURRENT_POINTS_KEY] = numPoints
        }
    }
}
```

> save points methode

```
class SavePoints {
    companion object {
        @Composable
        fun savepoints(numPointsToSave : Int) {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            val datastore = PointsData(context)

            LaunchedEffect(1) {
                scope.launch {
                    datastore.SaveCurrentPoints(numPointsToSave)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and whenever i want to get the number of points from my DataStore i use

```
val pointsdatastore = PointsData(context)
val currentpoints = pointsdatastore.getpoints.collectAsState(initial = 0)
//display it as text for example
                Text(text = currentpoints.value.toString(), fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = Color.White)
```

and to do the operation i want (add +1 o the already existing points i do this

```
 val pointsdatastore = PointsData(context)
    val currentpoints = pointsdatastore.getpoints.collectAsState(initial = 0)
SavePoints.savepoints(numPointsToSave =  currentpoints.value + 1)
```

but it doesn't seem to work because the number of points always stays 1.

**if you know whats the problem please help**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer my self but for anyone who is stuck in same situation the solution is to another method in PointsData(look at the question provided code)

> the method is:

```
suspend fun incrementpoints(){
        context.datastore.edit { preferences->
            val currentpoints = preferences[CURRENT_POINTS_KEY] ?: 0
            preferences[CURRENT_POINTS_KEY] = currentpoints + 1

        }
    }
```

**(if you want decrement not increment you can just change + to - )**

and now in the PointsMethod(look at the question provided code) you should add

```
@Composable
        fun incrementpoints() {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            val datastore = PointsData(context)

            LaunchedEffect(key1 = 1) {
                scope.launch {
                    datastore.incrementpoints()
                }
            }

        }
```